Is it possible to use Kotlin Deferred to return a suspended response of a REST request?
Is it possible to use Deferred in Kotlin to return a suspended response of a REST request?
If yes, how to do it without errors?
I made such an endpoint in Kottlin, Quarkus:
import jakarta.validation.Valid
import jakarta.ws.rs.Consumes
import jakarta.ws.rs.POST
import jakarta.ws.rs.Path
import jakarta.ws.rs.Produces
import jakarta.ws.rs.core.MediaType
import kotlinx.coroutines.CompletableDeferred
import kotlinx.coroutines.Deferred
@Path("/test")
class TestDeferredResult {

    @POST
    @Path("/deferred")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    fun test(@Valid rq: String): Deferred<String> {
        val res: Deferred<String> = CompletableDeferred("Result for request:" + rq)
        return res
    }
}

I get an error when returning the result:
HTTP Request to /test/deferred failed, error id: eaf0a221-f5c2-4663-87ce-e8611f8618d2-1: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: kotlinx.atomicfu.AtomicRef

Yes, you can use Kotlin's Deferred to return a suspended response in a REST request. By leveraging Kotlin's suspend functions, you can asynchronously handle network calls. The Deferred object allows you to manage the result of a long-running task, ensuring efficient handling of REST responses in a non-blocking way.

Thank you!
Can you suggest how to fix my code to avoid ClassNotFoundException ?
